# How do I properly prevent child rerender on change value?

Tags: reactjs, state, react-functional-component

I'm trying to create a Form Component where I have multiple fields added as children of a parent.
The parent component will hold the state for the values of the children.

How do I properly hold these values and handle changes in the state without having to rerender all the children? I would like to rerender only the one that changed.

For textboxes, I know that are other alternatives, but I'm using just as example of rerendering. In my real-world case I have a different component (toggle button).

I created a CodeSandbox to share this behavior:
https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-black-lnvhh

Answer (score 0):

## PureComponent

Use the Pure component api. This will only re-render if its props actually change

```
class MyComponent extends React.PureComponent {
```

from the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html)

> React.PureComponent is similar to React.Component. The difference between them is that React.Component doesn’t implement shouldComponentUpdate(), but React.PureComponent implements it with a shallow prop and state comparison.

## Memo

If your component is a functional component you can use React.memo

```
const MyComponent = React.memo(function MyComponent(props) {
  /* render using props */
});
```

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html)

> React.memo is a higher order component. It’s similar to React.PureComponent but for function components instead of classes.

Comment: I'm using the Memo in the Textbox. If that's the solution, Is it possible to edit the codebox, so I know what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`React.memo` is comparing properties passed to the component and rerendering it on change (it is a shallow comparison - but it doesn't really matter here).

In your case, you define `changed()` in `<App>` on each rerender of the App component and a function passed to the `FormContent` is not the same.

```
const App = () => {
  const changed = values => {
    console.log(values);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FormContent onChange={changed} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

To avoid it you can extract `changed()` definition and put it above component declaration:

```
const changed = values => {
  console.log(values);
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FormContent onChange={changed} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

This is a good solution if you don't change state in that function. If you want to keep that function inside a component and stop rerendering of the child component you should use `useCallback` hook.

```
const changed = useCallback(() => { return (values) => console.log(values) }, []);
```

It was created to solve that issue. `[]` at the end is a dependencies array and it behaves the same as in `useEffect()`.

> **useCallback**
>
> Pass an inline callback and an array of dependencies. useCallback will return a memoized version of the callback that only changes if one of the dependencies has changed. This is useful when passing callbacks to optimized child components that rely on reference equality to prevent unnecessary renders (e.g. shouldComponentUpdate).

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback

Comment: Sorry if It wasn't clear. In my example, I tried to express that the rerender happens when i change the FormContent state. The changed function created at the app was just a function to log the state values in console, so I could debug.

I updated the example.